# Loading @Font-face with eot file issues

Tags: css, sass, font-face

I am trying to load a font from a folder using sass like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "myFont";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("/wwwroot/assets/fonts/sampleFont.otf") format("embedded-opentype")
}

h1 {
    font-family: "myFont";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    color:#fff;
}
```

The problem is that I can't see the font been applied (i am currently using chrome and I have also tested it on Edge without success)
The path seems correct else webpack would have failed the build.
Is there anything I am missing or misunderstood?

Comment: i think you have to remove  font-weight and font-style from your @font-face , because you're just defining a font family

Comment: That didnt solve the issue